# After spliting String into ArryList<String> i cannot read the text from any cell

Tags: android, arraylist, split

I am an android noobie. What I am trying to do is to make this String an ArrayList. This is done. When i Print it On (with tv.setText) , the result is what i need but in this if i have right below i cannot find the "1". 
The result i want to have is to store the text between the noumbers inside another ArrayList but to go there i have to be able to read the strings from the ArrayList.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String text = "1Hello12People22Paul22Jackie21Anna12Fofo2";
TextView tv;
List<String> chars = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    PrinThemNow();
}

public void PrinThemNow(){
    chars = Arrays.asList(text.split(""));
    tv.setText(toString().valueOf(chars));

    for(int i=0;i<chars.size();i++){
        if(toString().valueOf(chars.get(i)) ==  " 1"){
            Toast.makeText(this,"I found One",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //This if is not working while the TV's text shows " 1"
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, just a tip, from `string` to `char[]` you can use

```
char[] chars = myString.toCharArray();
```

because it has no sense to save a `char array` as a `string ArrayList`

---

but now the problem. you have your string and you wanna print the text between the numbers.

It's not really clear what is your goal but lets try.

***I will suppose you used the char[] because it's 10 times better and easier***

## case 1) you wanna print text betweens "1"s

```
//lets loop the chars
bool firstOneFound = false;
int firstOccurrence = -1;
int secondOccurrence = -1;
int i = 0;
for(char c : chars){
  //is it equals to 1?
  if(c.equals('1')){
    //check if we are already after the first 1
    if(firstOneFound){
      //if yes, we found the final one
      secondOccurrence = i;
      break;
    }
    else{
      //this is the first occurrence
      firstOccurrence = i;
      firstOneFound = true;
    }
  }
  i++;
}
if(firstOccurrence != -1 && secondOccurrence != -1){
  String myFinalString = myString.subString(firstOccurrence, secondOccurrence);
}
```

## case 2) you wanna print all text except numbers (maybe with a space instead)

```
for(char c : chars){
  //check if it's a number
  if(c >= '0' && c <= '9'){
    //replace the number with anything else
    c = ' '; //if you wanna have it as a space
  }
}
//print the final string
String myFinalString = new String(chars);
```

## NOTE:

You can also use ArrayList of string, just replace `'` with `"`

hope it helps